# Batch If Exist inside For loop not working?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm writing a batch file that loops through the local drives on a PC and tests for the existence of a file in the root of the drive.  If the file exists, I want tyo do something & if it doesn't exist I want to do something else, but the If Exists statement isn't working.  Here's the code snippett:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%D in ('"wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get name /format:value"') do (
  echo %%D
  if exist %%D\file.txt (
    echo Processing Drive %%D
    Do Something ...
  ) else (
    Do Something Else ...
  )
)
goto :EOF
```

If I move the If block out of the For loop and label it as a subroutine in the batch file and call it from within the For loop it works fine, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work when inside the For loop.

Comment: Sorry but "isn't working" isn't helpful. Can you elaborate on that part?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `echo %%D` line with `echo ...[%%D]...` you will see why it fails.

WMIC output includes an aditional carriage return in its output that needs to be removed

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
    '"wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get name /format:value"'
) do for %%D in (%%a) do (
  echo ....[%%D]....
  if exist %%D\file.txt (
    echo Processing Drive %%D
  ) else (
    echo Skipping Drive %%D
  )
)
goto :EOF
```

In this case, an aditional `for` will handle the problem removing the aditional CR.